# Android: How to include a confirmation when files are uploaded on a server?

Tags: android

I'm uploading a few input data like Name Age Phone Number Address, etc and an image onto a server in the following way-

```
public void ServerUpload(View v){
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.101:8080/TMC/AddUser?");
      try {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", DataFields.fname));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", DataFields.lname));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", DataFields.Age));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sex", DataFields.Sex));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("blood", DataFields.Blood));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", DataFields.Phone));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("add1", DataFields.Add1));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("add2", DataFields.Add2));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", DataFields.City));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("state", DataFields.State));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pin", DataFields.Pin));
    BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 3;
    Bitmap myBitmapcopy = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Bitmap thumbnail = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmapcopy, 60, 80, true);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String server_image =Util.byteToHex(imageBytes);//Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo", server_image));
    Date date = new Date(0);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", Long.valueOf(date.getTime()).toString()));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    httpclient.execute(httppost);

  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Now, it works perfectly and the server receives the data too. However, when I touch the Upload button, I have no way of knowing whether it successfully updated or not, except by checking on the server itself.

I could display a "Uploaded Succesfully" Toast, or exit the function or do a dozen other things to show a confirmation of successful uploading.

My question is, where in the code snippet, do I insert the code to trigger the successful uploading response?

Comment: Probably you can use `finally` block of try-catch for doing that.

Comment: and you can use `AsyncTask` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it be checking response code of `HttpPost` object by doing this.

```
HttpResponse httpResp = httpclient.execute(response);
int code = httpResp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

if(code == 200){
  // Success , server processing done successfully,

} else {

   //Whenever fail due to some region 
}
```

The meaning of `200` is your `httppost` operation was done successfully , if any problem is happen with server it will through other status code like , 500, 401, 415 etc.

You can read more about http status code. here,
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

You can also read for other status code.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways of doing it, first would be to write a code on your server side to `echo` some sort of positive/negative response according to your query execution. Second option is to check for status code for `httppost` in your java code. And the third option would be to use `Boolean` variable in your java code and modifying the variable inside `try{...} catch(Exception e){...}` and then displaying `Toast` according to the value of `Boolean` variable inside `finally{...}` block. I will provide code snippets below for all three methods.

->  Returning success message from server (assuming you are using `php` for server side operations)

```
$sql = "UPDATE mytable ....."; 
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
 if ($result){ 
   echo "Success"; 
 } 
 else { 
   echo "Fail"; 
 }   
//This option would surely work.
//you can use json response aswell.
```

--> Check for status code of the `httppost` in java

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
int statuscode= response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

if(statuscode == 200){
   // Toast success message here
 } else {
    //Toast fail message here
 }
 //This option has limitations as it will not catch all errors
 //occurring on server side while query execution or inserting data in database
```

--> Using `Boolean` variable in java code

```
Boolean isUploaded; //Test variable to check the response from web
//
//Declare you `httppost` and `httpclient` here
//
try{
  //add your `namevaluepair` here
  //make the network request
  ...
  ...
  //and then modify the test variable at the last line of try block 
  isUploaded = true; 
}catch (ClientProtocolException e){
  //log your error here and modify the test variable
  isuploaded = false;
}catch(IOException e){
  //log your error here and modify the test variable
  isuploaded = false;
}finally {
  //finally toast the message depending upon the value of test variable
  if(!isUploaded){
     //Toast unsuccessful result message here
  }else{
     //Toast successful message here
  }
}
```

**Note:**  It is highly recommended that you use `AsyncTask` to make network requests in android apps.